# A new badge proposal - "John List"

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request, negative-badges

I have recently noticed several cases where people edited posts (not mine), by changing some minor 1-2 character spelling issues.

While this in and of itself is probably a good thing (it's well-known that poor wording and spelling errors make stuff much harder to read/comprehend), it is probably at least partially driven by the race for the "Strunk & White" badge. It also strongly points to the editor having OCD (Obsessive-Compulsive Disorder) since they notice the little errors to fix :)

So, I propose a semi-serious *"[John Emil List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_List)"* badge (named after a criminal who famously had OCD that contributed to him evading the law for a pretty long while).

The badge would be awarded for extremely high proportion of the edits that amounted to less than 3 character differences, say 50%+ of your edits, for people who have 50+ edits.

Comment: Awaiting for someone to notice that I had a parenthesis unclosed and edit to fix that in 1, 2, 3...

Comment: @Downvoter That was MY edit. MINE! ..... Jerk.. :P

Comment: @dvk, The _love_ character?

Comment: @Chacha, Well I'm gonna to go then. And I don't need any of this. I don't need this stuff, and I don't need you. I don't need anything except this. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079367/quotes

Comment: I have a feeling that this is targeted, at least in part, at me.  I already have my S&W badge, thankyouverymuch, but the OCD call is likely on target.  Really, those mistakes (it's vs. its, especially) just jump out at me like big blinding red lights.

Comment: This revision history just keeps getting funnier and funnier

Comment: Not planning to knock over any banks anytime soon, though.

Comment: I thought it was for SO users who had been arrested for soliciting.

Comment: @Michael Petrotta - it was not your edits that inspired the idea, sorry...

Comment: Downvoter, Chacha102, voyager, please step over here.

Comment: @chacha, please bold the opening parenthesis if you want to keep the closing one like that, the lack of symmetry is driving me crazy

Comment: I don't think lots of micro-edits is something that we should be encouraging.

Comment: @Downvoter - the heart character was placed into the text by an editor. I'm not quite sure which particular DSM-IV disorder to attribute that edit to :)

Comment: @Zoredache: I think we've made that point.

Comment: how is it that 12 prior edits failed to notice the question was proposing a new badge?  someone please fix the title to match.

Comment: turning CW in ... three, two, one...

Comment: ... Although, didn't Plato once claim that "love is a grave mental disease"?

Comment: @DVK: "<3" == ♡. "less than three" == "< 3"

Comment: You do realize that the real comments of this post are going on in the revision history?

Comment: @Cha, you saw my Eric Idle and raised a George Carlin! Well played.

Comment: @Chacha102 - No they ain't no more :) All comments are to be aboveboard and all edits are to be <3 characters! :)

Comment: I won the CW lottery @~qu

Comment: @voyager - OK, I'm lost. What does "<" sign have to do with ASCII? Did I make a pun and not get it myself?

Comment: @Downvoter - Actually, **I** won the CW lottery - it happened right before down-voters piled on

Comment: I disagree with the idea; tongue in cheek or not, badges should be positive.

Comment: @Downvoter, @DVK: sorry, Downvoter.  there must be a bug in the revision page's CW indication; first time i saw it was after Chacha102's rev.16.  sounds like DVK got there first.

Comment: @~qu, I see this at revision 18: added 310 characters in body; [made Community Wiki]

Comment: If we gave a badge to everyone who had OCD, everyone here would get one.

Comment: @dvk, the downvotes probably are a consequence of the post turning CW, it's cheaper!

Comment: You people keep talking about OCD when you know it really should be CDO.  The letters need to be alphabetical. :-p

Comment: CDOs are SOOOOO 2007.

Comment: @Downvoter: yup, that's what i see now; if it gets edited again the *[made CW]* will be put on the new revision.  that's the bug.

Comment: @~qu, is it reported?

Comment: @Down: no idea; haven't gone searching for an existing bug report.

Comment: @Down: hmm.  that's not the bug.  looks like maybe rev.17 was a rollback (to rev.9 maybe) which may have reset the CW flag.

Comment: Wonder if this is a record negative score on MSO for a new badge request :)

Answer (score 5):

Once the game is over, the King and the pawn go back in the same box.
Italian Proverb

-->

"I'm good enough," the King said, "only I'm not strong enough. You see, a minute goes by so fearfully quick. You might as well try to stop a Bandersnatch!"

Lewis Carroll (http://www.literature.org/authors/carroll-lewis/through-the-looking-glass/chapter-07.html)
-->

Comment: AKA: The quotes answer.

Comment: Lol, 9 reviews :D

Answer (score 0):

Badges should be [positive only](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/badges-positive-only/).

Comment: As I noted in the question, I personally view such edits as a net positive and thus **worthy** of boosting with a badge.

Comment: I don't think everyone sees it that way. Badges should be clearly positive.

Comment: Then those who don't see it that way should explicitly explain WHY such edits are not positive. I actually substantiated my point of view with a proper explanation :)

Comment: @DVK, naming a badge after an OCD criminal doesn't really make it sound very positive to me.

Comment: @Zoredache - I am perfectly happy if someone comes up with a better pithy name for the badge. I never claimed the name was good. What's in question is the idea of that badge.

Comment: I still believe that many would be offended, and it does not matter if they are justly offended or not - they're going to be angry. Nobody wants SO visitors to be angry.